# How to delete a file from external storage android studio, using only Uri

Tags: android, android-studio, video, uri

So I have taken a look at examples from other people and implemented this.

```
 File delete= new File(uri.getPath());
    if(delete.exists()){
        Log.d("Delete", "File Exists");
        if(delete.delete()){
            Log.d("Deleted", ""+uri);
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Unable to delete", ""+uri);
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.d("Delete", "File is not found");
    }
```

Now the only problem is that the path name i get is "content://downloads/all_downloads/644", and according to my printed logcat, This file could not be found. Note: This file does exist and I used the same uri to actually play the video. Thank you for your help. EDIT: OK This is how I got my URI.

```
BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("REFERENCE", "E"+"Entering Broadcast");
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        uri=( manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(referenceId));
    }
};
```

Now I appreciate very much for the suggestions given bellow, but I am still stuck even after reading the documentation. Suppose I cannot delete using a Uri, is there a way to convert my uri into something useful instead. I don't want to manually enter the address to the location of my files.

@Here is my entire code...

public class Cacher {

```
private DownloadManager manager;
private Uri uri;

public Cacher(String urlIn , Context context){

    Log.d("REFERENCE", "A1- casher");
    manager= (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Log.d("REFERENCE", "A");
    Uri temp=Uri.parse(urlIn);
    Log.d("REFERENCE", "B");
    DownloadManager.Request request= new DownloadManager.Request(temp);
    //
    request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    Long reference=manager.enqueue(request);
    // Toast.makeText(this,""+reference,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    Log.d("REFERENCE", "C"+"Downloading video");
    Log.d("REFERENCE", "D"+"Setting broadcast");
    context.registerReceiver(onComplete,
            new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    Log.d("REFERENCE", "F"+"Now Setting the uri table with");
}

BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("REFERENCE", "E"+"Entering Broadcast");
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        uri=( manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(referenceId));

    }
};
//TODO: Add Utility to remove all Cached Videos
//TODO: Add Utility to delete a single cached video after it has been watched.

public Uri getUri() {
    return uri;
}
```

}

Comment: see `ContentResolver` documentation

Comment: Actually, you need to load this info from contentresolver

Comment: for 100% deleting, you should use `DATA` columns `(new file(DATA).delete())` for api 28 and lower. and use `getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null)` for api 29 and higher. api 29 automatic remove file. good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution to my problem for those who do not want to read through our comments. First, chose a directory to download to. Then use that files path and use the delete() functionality. Keep in mind that once you create a directory with a folder name, you only need to reference the folder name and not the entire path. Here is the code I hope it helps:

```
    String in= GenerateDirectory.createVideoDirectory(context);// Might be useless here.
    manager= (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Uri temp=Uri.parse(urlIn);
    Ringtone r= RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, temp);
    String filename=(r.getTitle(context));
    DownloadManager.Request request= new DownloadManager.Request(temp);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/secretVideos", filename);
    uri=Uri.parse(in+"/"+filename);
    Log.d("REFERENCE", "Uri that is returned "+uri);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    manager.enqueue(request);
```

// And then

```
 public void removeCache(){
    //TODO: Fix this. For some reason the Uri used gives invalid path name.
    Log.d("Delete", "Directory to find ... "+uri);
    File delete= new File(uri.getPath());
    if(delete.exists()){
        Log.d("Delete", "File Exists");
        if(delete.delete()){
            Log.d("Deleted", ""+uri);
        }
    }
}
```

// Where I create the directory

```
 private int RESULT=0;
  public static String createVideoDirectory(Context context){
      String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
      File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage + "/" + "secretVideos");
      if(!appDirectory.exists()){
          Log.d("Directory","Directory DNE");
            if(appDirectory.mkdir()) {
             Log.d("Directory", "Directory  Created");

             //Log.d("Directory","Unable to create directory, using default directory");
            }
            else if(appDirectory.canWrite()){
                Log.d("Directory", "Permission given");
      }
            else{
                Log.d("Directory", "Lack of permission");
            }
      }

      else{
          Log.d("Directory","Already Exists");
      }


    return appDirectory.toString();
}
private void writeAndReadPermissions(Context context){
      if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, RESULT);

      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So I have taken a look at examples from other people and implemented this.

That would only work if the `Uri` has a `file` scheme and you have write access to the directory that holds the file.

> How to delete a file from external storage android studio, using only Uri

Most likely, you don't.

If you get the `Uri` from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, wrap the `Uri` in a `DocumentFile` using `fromSingleUri()`, then call `delete()` on the `DocumentFile`.

For any other `content` `Uri`, you are welcome to try calling `delete()` on a `ContentResolver`, but do not expect it to work. There is no requirement that a `ContentProvider` offer you any way to delete a piece of content. The app that supplies the `ContentProvider` should have its own way of allowing users to delete things.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand. I am fairly new to Android development. I get my Uri this way...

Comment: BroadcastReceiver onComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("REFERENCE", "E"+"Entering Broadcast");
            long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
            uri=( manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(referenceId));
        }
    };

Comment: @NamanJain: If `manager` is a `DownloadManager`, you should not need a `Uri`, as you told `DownloadManager` where to download the content in your `DownloadManager.Request`. Use whatever you passed to one of the `setDestination...()` methods on `DownloadManager.Request` to access and delete the content.

Comment: @CommonsWare hmmm, did you have any problems with `DownloadManager`'s [ContentProvider#delete](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadProvider.java#1259) method?  why to treat that `Uri` differently?

Comment: @pskink: "did you have any problems with DownloadManager's ContentProvider#delete method?" -- there is no requirement for a `ContentProvider` to support `delete()` for anything. Even when it does, it does not have to support `delete()` for a stream (versus a database row or something else). `ContentProvider` is an API to be implemented; the implementation details are up to the provider's developer. While it is possible that this particular `Uri` may come from `DownloadManager`, neither the question title nor most of the body explains that, and so my answer is for `Uri` values in general.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank You for the suggestion, however I have not declared the exact location I want the file to be stored.  I used the default location which is the downloads folder. The only placeholder I have is getting the Uri using the reference ID of the video downloaded. Please take a look at my update it includes more code.

Comment: @NamanJain: Personally, I would not offer a delete option. The user can do that either via the Downloads app or through other tools (e.g., file manager). This is akin to what a Web browser would do. You are certainly welcome to try `delete()` on `ContentResolver` and see if that deletes the underlying file, but I would not count on it working.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I dont want to give user the ability to delete. I am making an app similar to Netflix. I want the user to be able to download my videos, and once the video is completed, auto-delete it.

Comment: @NamanJain: "I am making an app similar to Netflix" -- Netflix does not use `DownloadManager`, AFAIK. "once the video is completed, auto-delete it" -- download to a specific location (so you can delete the file directly). Or, as I have written a few times now, you are certainly welcome to try `delete()` on `ContentResolver` and see if that deletes the underlying file, but I would not count on it working.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of an example of ContentResolver. I cannot see how it is being implemented. As for Netflix, do you and any idea what they might be using? I want to implement a nice and easy to use method.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare, you seem to know your stuff well. DO you mind answering this question as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588988/how-to-save-video-downloaded-from-download-manager-in-internal-storage-of-app-di

Comment: @NamanJain: "Can you please provide an example of an example of ContentResolver" -- ummm, `getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null)`, off the top of my head. "do you and any idea what they might be using?" -- I don't know if they even use HTTPS for downloads. If they are, most likely they are using an HTTP client API for those downloads (e.g., OkHttp), since they will be downloading to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html).

Comment: Ok. So I have now been able to successfully store the file in a desired location. However, when I try to delete it, it will not work in the answer where you said "Use whatever you passed to one of the     setDestination...()". I cannot pass that address, and if I do my file is not found to be deleted.

Comment: @NamanJain: I suggest that you post a separate Stack Overflow question with a fresh [mcve]. That [mcve] would include: the code where you are configuring the `DownloadManager.Request`, the code where you are determining that you have "been able to successfully store the file in a desired location", and the code that reflects "I cannot pass that address, and if I do my file is not found to be deleted".